# Quick Question - Approximate distribution for sample mean?

Tags: probability, self-study, mathematical-statistics, central-limit-theorem, mean

[image][image]

I am having issues answering part two.

I think it is about CLT, correct me if I'm wrong.

But how do you compute the distribution details from this ?

Please help and thank you for all your contributions.

Please answer it using the main question AND part one which is about the expression.

Comment: Please add the `self-study` tag and read its [tag wiki info](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) carefully, modifying your question if necessary to conform to the request there. I'd assume the intent is for you to invoke the CLT. What information do you need to specify a normal distribution?

Comment: @Glen_b   Done. Could you please demonstrate how to compute those information? that's the bit I am stuck.

Comment: Please don't pester people. Note that at the link I gave in my first comment, we will offer 'helpful hints' rather than give answers (we're not here to do your homework *for* you). I gave you one helpful hint already, but you didn't respond to it. What are your thoughts on the question at the end of my previous comment?

Comment: Heres another, related one: what does the CLT actually say?

Comment: @Glen_b: My own attempt after your post is that it is Normal. And the mean of approximate distribution is 60(same as the mean of negative binomial given) and the standard deviation is the SD of negative binomial divided by sqrt of n, which is 1140/sqrt(n). Could you please confirm ?

Comment: I don't think the second question is asking about the negative binomial. Note it asks about $\bar X$ and $X$ is defined at the start of the question to be discrete uniform.

Comment: @Glen_b: but it says 'for large n' which is mentioned in the first part ? So how would you answer this question instead ?

Comment: I'd work out the mean and variance (or mean and standard deviation) of $\bar X$.

Comment: @Glen_b: I really have no idea. Could you at least show me how to compute the variance of sample mean please ?

Comment: Or just the mean ? As I really don't know where to start.

Comment: It follows directly from basic properties of [expectation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Linearity) and [variance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Basic_properties). Hint: write the mean as a constant times a sum. I really can't teach you a whole subject in comments. Where's your textbook? Notes? ... and so on? In fact if you really can't get started at all, I don't think this is the right forum for you.

Comment: I still don't understand why this is unrelated to the negative bino in the previous part ? As it clearly mentions 'large n' and what's the point of having part G ( the order of subparts)when you could've answered it using first principles ?

Comment: What "G" are you talking about? My reasoning is based on the fact that it refers to $\bar X$. We have a variable defined to be $X$. The thing you point to is not defined to be $X$.

Answer (score 2):

As you suggest the last part of the question seems to be looking for you to apply the CLT.

As such you would probably be expected to specify the mean and variance of the distribution of $\bar X$ and invoke the CLT to give an approximate distribution for it.

The mean and variance of $\bar X$ can be found using elementary properties of [expectation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Linearity) and [variance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Basic_properties), such as:

$\text{E}[a X + b Y] = a \text{E}[X] + b \text{E}[Y]\,$

$\text{Var}(aX+bY)=a^2\text{Var}(X)+b^2\text{Var}(Y)+2ab\, \text{Cov}(X,Y),$

(if $X$ and $Y$ are independent, the covariance term will be 0.)

Note that $X$ is defined in the question.

Comment: I really want to learn how to do it, Glen. And I appreciate your help. In the first part it says '...turns up on the n-th roll' and in the second part 'for a large n...'. Does that imply that the mean and SD should come from the negative bino instead ? I know you said no but could you give a reason because I think there is a reason that these two parts are arranged in such an order ?

Comment: I have explained my reasoning already. I won't second guess it further. Take it up with the person who gave you the question.

Comment: is it possible that the question itself is wrong (lol) ?

Comment: Could you take a look at this are an of those approaches correct ? I know the first one isnt.http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/832464/approximate-distribution-for-the-sample-mean

Comment: Please *don't* cross post questions to multiple SE sites; this is explained in the [help](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (3rd-last paragraph). Since you posted there first, you should direct all your questions there. Please also take the trouble to read all the help.